# Escaping quotes of an entry string used inside a script tag

Tags: javascript, escaping, escape

How can I display an entry string, with included special characters (like single and double quotes) , inside a script tag without translating these special characters into html entities but escaping their quotes?

By default: `Carlo's "string"` will output `Carlo&#039;s &quot;string&quot;` which in javascript if the variable is shown on screen will show all the characters of the html entities.

I have tried:

```
<script>
   var string = '{{ creatif.creatifsName|raw }}'
</script>
```

Which removes the html entities but obviously the script will not work because the quotes are not escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
   var mystring = '{{ creatif.creatifsName|escape('js') }}'
</script>
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html

Remember to wrap your variable declaration in quotes for it to be set as a string in the JS.

Comment: Great, thank you so much!!!